# Is Spyder pointed to the wrong folder or is my setup totally wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I was using Spyder just fine until a few hours ago. Now, I realize, there are two ways to access Spyder, as seen in the image below.

[image]

I guess something just recently changed, but I'm not sure what it is. Anyway, if I click on the first icon, nothing happens. This used to open my Spyder IDE. If I click on the second icon, the Spyder IDE opens and I see this.

[image]

Now, when I select that single line of code and hit F9, I get a message that says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'` However, Pandas is already installed. if I open the Anaconda Prompt and type 'pip install pandas' it confirms that Pandas is already installed.

[image]

What is wrong with my setup? How can I reset things to the way they were a few hours ago?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to import pandas using Spyder. If you must use Spyder (spyder-env), you can try typing "conda install -n spyder-env pandas" in cmd. Then enter "conda list -n spyder-env | findstr pandas", if content is produced, it means that the pandas download was successful. You can give it a try. I saw this content on the following Chinese website, URL: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/339662352. By the way, you can learn about Conda Virtual Environment online.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling, and then reinstalling, the app. Now everything works fine. Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).